# Chrome equivalent for gBrowser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering what the equivalent call to the Chrome API Would be for this line?

```
var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent.  The APIs are different.  If you want the history, for example, you'd need to use the [`chrome.history` module](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html).  If you want to control what pages are loaded in what tabs, you'd need to use the [`chrome.tabs` module](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html), and so on.

The various extension capabilities are covered in the [developer's guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html).